# How to share Accounts to the partner portal users?

Tags: apex, trigger, sharing

I have a Custom object(PartnerInformation__c) it has two lookup fields **Account Customer** (lookup to customer Accounts) **Account Partner**(lookup to Partner Accounts).

When Partner login into the Portal he has access to **PartnerInformation__c** records but when he tries to access **Account Customer** records it is giving **insufficient privileges**.

I want to provide access to the Customer Accounts also. Can anyone please help me how to give access using any trigger or some other procedure ?

I tried below code but its giving **Too many DML rows: 10001**

```
trigger AccShare on PartnerInformation__c (after insert,after Update) {

    List<AccountShare> aShares = new List<AccountShare>();
    if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate ){

        Set<Id> Ids = new Set<Id>();
        for(PartnerInformation__c p : trigger.new){
            Ids.add(p.AccountParter__r.Id);
            System.debug('Debug1' + Ids); // It is returning null

        }
        List<User> usrs = [Select Id,Name,AccountId from User where AccountId IN: Ids]; // It is querying all as Ids are null
            System.debug('Debugg 2 ' + usr);
        for(PartnerInformation__c p : trigger.new){

             for(User u: usr){

              AccountShare acc= new AccountShare();

                acc.UserOrGroupId = u.id;
                acc.AccountAccessLevel = 'edit';

               aShares.add(acc);
            }
        }
        }

        Database.SaveResult[] ShareInsertResult = Database.insert(aShares,false); // It is giving Too many DML Rows 10001 because it is inserting everything
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Relationship fields ("__r") are always initially null in a trigger. You need to use the lookup field ("__c") to get the ID values:

```
for(PartnerInformation__c record: Trigger.new) {
    if(record.AccountPartner__c <> null) {
        Ids.add(record.AccountPartner__c);
    }
}
```